Lookup Multi control - is there a client side JS API like SPClientPeoplePicker?
I have a Lookup field for which I am allowing multiple values, however I want the list of available options on the left side of the multi-select to be filtered by another control on the form.
I can get that to happen just fine. Depending on the value of a specific drop-down, I show only the options I want on the left side of the control (the "_SelectCandidate" <select> box). If the value of the drop-down changes, I clear the "candidate" box and re-populate with the newly filtered options.  Easy peasy. And the "Add" button works just fine, the selected option is moved to the right hand <select> box (the "_SelectResult" box), and the hidden <input> that stores the encoded value of all selected options gets populated correctly.
The problem is what happens when the "Remove" button is clicked. If the "Remove" button is clicked, the option is moved back to the "candidate" box, but all the original (unfiltered) options re-appear.
I noticed there is another hidden <input> whos id ends with "_MultiLookup_data" that looks like it stores the value of all the original options.  So I tried changing that <input>'s value to only have the filtered list of options, thinking that maybe Microsoft's code uses that value to re-populate the "candidate" box, but that didn't work. Even if I set the "_MultiLookup_data" <input> to have only my few filtered options, all the original unfiltered options still re-appear in the "candidate" box when "Remove" is clicked.  So obviously those values are cached somewhere.
Which leads me to wonder, is there a client-side JS API I can hook into to manipulate the behavior of the overall multi-select control, similar to how you can use SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict to get to APIs where you can manipulate the people picker controls on a form?
Or does anyone know where that original list of options is cached, so I can clear it and set it with just my filtered options?
